# Disable binary logs in K8S managed mysql server

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I am a novice with K8S and have a problem with binary logs that are using almost all space of server. Currently a solution is to remove these logs every day, so server wouldn't crash.

From MySQL:

> To disable binary logging, you can specify the --skip-log-bin or --disable-log-bin option at startup. If either of these options is specified and --log-bin is also specified, the option specified later takes precedence.

I believe that the best strategy would be to stop MySQL server and start again with --disable-log-bin option. My concern is that dropping a pod where MySQL server runs may remove all the data in server. Also, usually when dropping pod it just restarts automatically and that doesn't allow to add option to server start.

The question would be simple, how to disable binary logs safely in K8S managed MySQL server?

Comment: make a backup and restore it after words

Comment: Yes, backup is necessary. But how to add option --skip-log-bin that mysql would run when started? If I delete pod, the new pod image would start the same way: without --skip-log-bin option.

Comment: You call should be like `kubectl create configmap mysql-config --from-file=my.cnf` add it to the my.cnf file